# Getting empty cluster result with vectordump command in mahout kmeans algorithm

Tags: linux, mahout, k-means

i have installed and started hadoop and run the below commands

```
mahout seqdirectory -c UTF-8 -i Input_files -o seqfiles

mahout seq2sparse -i seqfiles/ -o vectorfiles/ -ow

mahout kmeans -i vectorfiles/tf-vectors/ -c initial-clusters -o kmeans-clusters -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -cd 1.0 -k 20 -x 20 -cl

mahout clusterdump -dt sequencefile -d vectorfiles/dictionary.file-0 -i kmeans-clusters/clusters-1-final -o result.txt -b 10 -n 10
```

and when i open my result.txt it is giving me

```
VL-1{n=2 c= all:1.00
     Top Terms:
```

below is my text sample text file

```
John is working in London
```

Please suggest me how to get the clusters for my sample text file

Answer (score 0):

Just one line is not enough. I did some hack

- Just create one dummy file in Folder Input_files with dummy words in
  it.

It shall run.
Please let me know if you get better solution